# Microsoft Excel formula - how to replace the cell reference in a function to other function

Tags: excel

I have data of multiple columns and multiple rows, like 2-D array. But all column doesn't have same number of rows. let say column1 has only data in 5 row while column2 has data in 10 rows. I need to create a drop down based on column. If Column1 has values in 5 rows then drop down will display 5 values. similarly for column2. I have used Index() function in formula to display whole column as drop down.

=INDEX($A$2:$I$11,,2)
here 2 is for 2nd column

Now My problem is, I need to replace the hard coded row number into function. here last row number is 11, I want to replace it to ROWS() funtion. Then how to write Index() function.

Simply My question is how to replace the cell reference in a function to other function ?

[image: Click here for data as image]

Comment: If row 1 contains the header to which can be used to choose particular column then you can use `MATCH` function in place of hard coded value e.g. `MATCH(CellHoldingHeaderToBeMatched,A1:I1,0)`.

Comment: How excel will know which column you want to use? Means what is the formula/method determine column?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `OFFSET` function with the `COUNTA` function for the `height` argument to get the right number of rows. Once you have created the first drop-down list, you can simply drag that cell to create the drop-down lists for all the other columns.

For example, you could enter the following formula for the drop-down list in cell A2 of your sample table:

```
=OFFSET(A3,,,COUNTA(A3:A99))
```

Note that in this example, the row range is hardcoded to avoid counting the rows with the column header and the drop-down cell itself by starting the row count at row 3 up to a randomly high row number (row 99) that will never be exceeded. In other situations, you may be able to simply include the entire column with `A:A` without ending up with blank options in the drop-down list.